# Easily creating a log-and-continue breakpoint in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode6, lldb

Frequently when I need to know if I've hit a point in code I'll drop in a `println("We made it this far")` statement. Sometimes this will get committed, or a coworker commits one of theirs, and eventually our codebase gets littered with them.

An alternative is to drop a breakpoint on that location in code and add a "Log Message" action, as well as check "Automatically continue after evaluating actions". However, this is a three-step process and dropping in a `println` remains the path of least resistance.

Is there an easier way to create this breakpoint than clicking the sidebar and right-clicking to edit? Is there a way to create this as a workflow using Automator or AppleScript and bind it to a hotkey?

Comment: It looks like the plugin 'Tuna' gets me most of the way there. https://github.com/dealforest/Tuna/issues/16

Comment: possible starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199689/add-file-breakpoint-in-xcode-4-via-applescript